How do you justify eternal hell punishment for shirk? [not a duplicate query please read full]
Every punishment has its severity according to its crime. So even if someone does delibritly shirk and by doing that obviously nothing would happen (affect) to the authority and Allah's power or oneness, so why so much hatred and severe ( eternal punishment ) that it doesn't have any actual consequence to Allah's power and dominian.
Even if you somehow justify this, still it won't make sense, because if shirk is a sinn to be that great "unforgivable and intolerable" then Allah woudn't create this world or atleast those people who would do shirk ( based on his knowledge of the future ) .
So its a catch 22 situation, if sin of shirk is that much "hated and intolereted" then God wouldn't Allow this creation on the first place because of the "hatered and intolerable" the sin of shirk is, if he Allows the creation (with it's sins of shirk) to happen then it means it shouldn't be an unforgiven sin and obviously no eternal hell as punishment.
Imagine it for yourself, if you hate something unconditionally will you allow that thing to happen (if you have the power), if yes,then in reality you didn't hate it to begin with.

Please reponse a instead of thumbs down

If life is a test this claim simply doesn't hold. Note any mushrik has a chance for forgiveness (repentance) till his last breath. As for why Allah wanted shirk to happen there are many plausible reasons, but all of us must be aware that: "He is not questioned about what He does, but they will be questioned."(21:23). I don't see here any relation to hatred as mentioned in your post. Otherwise where is the justice if a person who committed shirk all her life would be treated equally in the hereafter as a believer.

It seems you haven't comprehende the query I request you to read it patiently and unbiasedly then you would know I am trying to ask

Islam teaches that life is a test, and your question presupposes that we are unwilling participants in this test, that we weren't aware of this — particularly the consequences — before being subjected to it. According to the Qur'an, this is not the case:

72 Indeed, we offered the Trust to the heavens and the earth and the mountains, and they declined to bear it and feared it; but man bore it. Indeed, he was unjust and ignorant.
73 So that Allah may punish the hypocrite men and hypocrite women and the men and women who associate others with Him and that Allah may accept repentance from the believing men and believing women. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful.
— Al-'Ahzab 72-73

172 And when your Lord took from the children of Adam - from their loins - their descendants and made them testify of themselves, "Am I not your Lord?" They said, "Yes, we have testified." Lest you should say on the day of Resurrection, "Indeed, we were of this unaware."
— Al-'A`raf 172

Here, the Qur'an's statement is clear that we undertook the test willingly, despite retaining no memory of it when we are born in our physical bodies. This in spite of the potential punishment for failure, which was known and feared by the rest of the heavens and earth.
Allah created us all in a state of "fitrah", which includes an untainted natural inclination to worship God; while outside influences may pressure us to believe falsehoods throughout our lives, it is still our own choice to reject the truth when it becomes known to us. That is what we are punished for.
Allah, being All-Aware, knows whether we will succeed or fail as soon as we are created; He is not bound by time in the same way as we are and knows the future even when we can not. But he is also Just, and by letting us live our lives, righteous and sinner alike, we will know on the Day of Judgement that whatever punishment is coming to us is something that we have earned, that it's not just the whims of an arbitrary deity.
And if He only ever created those who He knew would pass the test, that's… not even really a test, is it?

I just said he could have not created those people who will do Shirk ( coz of it being a grave sin and intolerent towards the sin) and I  have not mentioned here other sins only Sin of shirk and it eternal hell consequencez.

@SulaimanGran A significant part of the test is that we accept Allah as Lord; shirk is a direct rejection of that. But you can't do either if you haven't been created.

Please read my question again and clearly then you woudn't commented this statement
